# How to link to some of the libraries statically and some dynamically in Visual studio's Linux projects?

Tags: visual-studio, g++, visual-studio-2019

I am writing a c++ Linux user-mode app in Visual studio. My app uses libraries like openssl and I need to link to these libraries statically. But the problem is, when I use the `-static` linker option, I face two problems:

1. I get warnings similar to:

> error : In function `dlfcn_globallookup': 1>dso_dlfcn.c : error :
> (.text+0x11): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked
> applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc
> version used for linking

2. When I use openssl APIs such as `SSL_library_init`, I get a segmentation fault and my program crashes, but when I remove the `-static` linker option, it works fine.

*I think* I can solve these two problems by linking to glibc dynamically and the other libraries statically (since currently adding `-static` causes glibc to link statically as well). The problem is, there is no option in the linker settings (That I can find) which gives me the option to choose whether I want a certain library to be linked statically or dynamically:

[image]

I currently write the `-static` in the Command Line's additional options to build statically, since I couldn't find a static option anywhere in the settings.

So my question is, how can I link to some of these libraries statically, and then link to the rest of the libraries dynamically as a way around the mentioned problems?